# problems with 2 fragments side by side

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Here is what I have going on in short.
I have two fragments showing when on horizontal orientation (listview and detailview) and a single fragment when in vertical orientation (listview).
Now when my app starts **I want** it to show the listview if there is **NO** `savedInstanceState` and display detailview when there is **A** `savedInstanceState`. you can see this action in android default email app when rotating it stays on the email no matter what orientation.

What's going on is it will display the `listview` when rotated to vertical.
This is my first time posting and I hope I can get some help, I am new to this.

```
public class TicketActivityP extends Activity implements OnSelectedListener {

boolean detailPage = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_view);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ListFragmentP listFragment = new ListFragmentP();
        ft.add(R.id.displayList, listFragment, "List_Fragment");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }

    if(findViewById(R.id.displayDetail) != null){
        detailPage = true;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        DetailFragmentP detailFragment = (DetailFragmentP) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);

        if(detailFragment == null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.displayDetail, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment1");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Did I get it correctly: you have both listview and detailsview showing up when in landscape mode and when you change to portrait mode you lose the details?

Comment: yes, I want the details to show up instead of the list.

Comment: you can also see the effect in messaging app. if you just opened it, it shows the list view, after you click on a message it shows in the detail view but now if you rotate it - it shows you the messages instead of the list. mine is showing the list by default after rotation.

Comment: You call `setContentView(R.layout.ticket_view);` and then you check `if(findViewById(R.id.displayDetail) != null)`. Does `ticket_view` have an element with that id?

Comment: in my layout-land version it does, but in the layout version it is just the displayList. I was thinking it had something to do with the setcontentview.

Comment: No I'm not sure what or where to add.

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean detailPage = false;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_view);

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ListFragmentP listFragment = new ListFragmentP();
        ft.add(R.id.displayList, listFragment, "List_Fragment");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.commit();
    }


    if(findViewById(R.id.displayDetail) != null){
        Log.d("tap","displayDetail found");
        detailPage = true;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        DetailFragmentP detailFragment = (DetailFragmentP) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);

        if(detailFragment == null){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            detailFragment = new DetailFragmentP();
            ft.replace(R.id.displayDetail, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment1");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }else{

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("acsi2000.db",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
            Cursor page_cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE Order_No='" + DetailFragmentP.Order_No + "'",null);
            DetailFragmentP detailFragment = new DetailFragmentP();
            detailFragment.setSMSOContent(page_cursor);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment2");
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();


        }

    }
}
@Override
public void onSelected(String SMSO) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("acsi2000.db",android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE ,null);
    Cursor page_cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE Order_No='" + SMSO + "'",null);
    if(detailPage){
        DetailFragmentP detailFragment = (DetailFragmentP) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.displayDetail);
        detailFragment.updateSMSOContent(page_cursor);
    }else{
        DetailFragmentP detailFragment = new DetailFragmentP();
        detailFragment.setSMSOContent(page_cursor);
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.displayList, detailFragment, "Detail_Fragment2");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

look like I needed to add a else statement to the R.id.displayDetail check, then check for saved instances and perform the same sort of code as my on selected.

Thanks for your help and I hope this helps some1 else.